# I want to set a rotation value for marker of leaflet via an input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have an HTML input tag of type range which I want to use to set the value for rotationAngle of leaflet marker. Also, the rotationAngle must get updated as the user changes the value of `<input>`.

Also I am using https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker
but cannot set the value using user input.

I want that as input tag value changes the rotationAngle goes on changes.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check out [How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and consider writing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update `rotationAngle` using [`setRotationAngle(newAngle)`](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker#api) method

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([50.5, 30.5], 18);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([50.5, 30.5], {
  rotationAngle: 0
}).addTo(map);

function updateAngle(input) {
  marker.setRotationAngle(input.value);
}
```

```css
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-rotatedmarker@0.2.0/leaflet.rotatedMarker.min.js"></script>


<input type="number" value="0" min="-360" max="360" onblur="updateAngle(this)">
<div id="map"></div>
```